# How to make custom dynamic Google Map Markers in Flutter (that includes network image) on top of a marker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr2ZZ.png)

The desired output is like the image.

Comment: you need to use `PictureRecorder`

Comment: @pskink could you explain it more

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html - `endRecording` returns a `Picture` on which you should call `toImage` method and finally calling `toByteData` on `Image` gives you raw bytes that you can pass to `BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can create these type of markers with help of this code.

```
  Set<Marker> markers = Set(); 

@override
void initState() {
addMarkers();
super.initState();
}

addMarkers() async {
   
String imgurl = "https://www.fluttercampus.com/img/car.png";
Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgurl))
  .load(imgurl))
  .buffer
  .asUint8List();

 markers.add(
 Marker( //add start location marker
markerId: MarkerId(carLocation.toString()),
position: carLocation, //position of marker
infoWindow: InfoWindow( //popup info 
  title: 'Car Point ',
  snippet: 'Car Marker',
),
icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes), //Icon for Marker
)
);

setState(() {
    //refresh UI
});
}
```

Now add this marker in the map

```
GoogleMap( //Map widget from google_maps_flutter package
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true, //enable Zoom in, out on map
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition( //innital position in map
                target: startLocation, //initial position
                zoom: 14.0, //initial zoom level
              ),
              markers: markers, //markers to show on map
              mapType: MapType.normal, //map type
              onMapCreated: (controller) { //method called when map is created
                setState(() {
                  mapController = controller; 
                });
              },
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! but I am getting image of the user without the marker(pin) so I am hoping if there is a way to overlay the image on top of the pin icon to achieve the desired goal. Any approach to achieve this?

Comment: can you explain your requirements in details

Comment: Sure! the image I get from backend is the profile picture of the user (on your answer the image you used is a car image within a location pin icon but on my case the network image is only the image without the location pin). the desred goal is to put the profile picture within the location pin icon and putting them together on the map